# Gefiltah Fish Erev Pesach

Tags: passover, halacha, matzah, food

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matzah meal before פסח](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/matzah-meal-before)

You are not allowed to eat Matzah on erev Pesach as we should have an appetite for the Matazah at the Seder my question is what if you have a food item that has Matazah in it like Gefiltah fish can you eat it on Erev Pesach ?