# Matzah meal before פסח

Tags: minhag, food, passover, matzah

On the subject of [not eating Matzah before פסח](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15264/5), may one eat products containing Matzah meal in that time?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120853/759

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is prohibited to eat Matzah on Erev Pesach, however cooked or boiled matzah-meal products are permitted according to all the Poskim. Fried Matzah-meal products, however, should be avoided (see Sha'ar ha-Tziyun 444:1). Baked Matzah-meal products, such as cakes or cookies, are prohibited; Harav S.Z. Auerbach (Erev Pesach Shechal b'Shabbos, pg. 207); Shevet ha-Levi 8:117.

Comment: What if you boiled it then baked it again?

Answer (score 10):

The Mishna Berura ([OC 471 sk 10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=159)) points out that one may eat Matza Ashira (eg. Egg Matza) on Erev Pesach because one cannot fulfill his obligation to eat matza on seder night with it. Seemingly the only things that are forbidden to eat are those with which one can fulfill his obligation to eat matza.

Products using matza meal which are cooked in liquid certainly cannot be used for the mitzva. ([Shulchan Aruch OC 461:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=124))

Comment: beat me by seconds once again. I thought the mishnah berura says the opposite? (471:1)

Comment: which mishna berura?

Comment: he clearly says in 471:10 like you. Whats his point in 471:1?

Comment: In :1 he's talking about the issues of keviat seuda samuch lemincha. In :10 he's talking about the issur matza on erev pesach (keboel arusato beveit chamiv).

Answer (score 5):

Hacham Ovadia Yosef, in Yabia Omer (O"C 6:39), permits cooked and fried Matza on Erev Pesach.

He concludes:

> ועכ"פ לדידן דנקטינן כרוב הפוסקים ומרן הש"ע (בסי' תעא ס"ב) שמותר
>   לאכול מצה עשירה בע"פ, **הוא הדין שמותר לאכול מצה מבושלת בע"פ**, אפילו
>   נתבשלה בע"פ.   וכדעת החק יעקב הנ"ל.   ואע"פ שהגרי"ח בשו"ת רב פעלים ח"ג
>   (חאו"ח סי' כז) ובס' בן איש חי (פר' צו אות כו) נראה שחושש לדברי הבית
>   דוד לאסור מצה שנתבשלה בע"פ, העיקר לדינא כדעת רוב האחרונים שהתירו,
>   ומהם, החק יעקב, והשלחן גבוה, ומהר"י נבארו בס' לב מבין, ומהר"א הכהן בס'
>   יוקח נא, ומהר"א ענתבי בס' חכמה ומוסר, ומהר"ם ישראל בס' משה ידבר, והרב
>   צל הכסף.   ומכיון שכל עיקר איסור אכילת מצה בע"פ אינו אלא מדרבנן, בודאי
>   שיש לסמוך על דעת האחרונים שפסקו להקל.   וכ"כ הגאון החסיד מהר"א מני
>   בזכרונות אליהו (מע' פ אות כב, עמוד לח).   ע"ש.   **וכן עיקר להתיר. 
>   ואין הבדל בזה בין מבושלת לבין מטוגנת בשמן.**   וכמ"ש בש"ע הגר"ז (סי' תעא
>   סעיף ט).   ובחיי אדם (כלל קכט סי' יג).   ואף שהפמ"ג (בא"א אות ח) כ',
>   שצ"ע במטוגנת בשמן בלי יין, אם מותר לאוכלה בע"פ, דשמא יוצאים בה י"ח
>   בליל פסח.   ע"ש.   נראה שאין ספקו מוציא מידי ודאי של הגר"ז והח"א.‏
>   **ולכן יש להקל גם במצה מטוגנת בשמן**.   והנלע"ד כתבתי.‏

Comment: FTR HaRav SZ Auerbach disagrees.

Comment: @GershonGold Hacham Ovadia backs himself with the Shulchan Aruch Harav and the Chayei Adam. Even the Pri Megadim only is *bisafek* when there's no third ingredient, but if there is, for example, wine, he permits it too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, I've heard on a lecture of R. Gidon Ben-Moshe that this is not forbidden.

Possibly you can find it on [this](http://gideon-ben-moshe.rabbi.name/) site among other his lectures.

Comment: Can someone explain me reasons for downvoting? There are lot of good answers here, I can delete mine if it is bad.

Comment: +1 from me. I think they might object to your lack of summary of his position and the vague sourcing. If you can be more concrete, that would be beneficial (IMO).